# Why does using the full path solved the can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: python, spacy

When I try to load `en_core_web_sm` from `spacy` with:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')get the following error:
```

the following error occurs:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I used the installation instructions from spacy.io:

```
pip3 install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip3 install -U spacy
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I solve this error, when using `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-3.2.0`.

Can someone explain to me, why I have to get the full path to `spacy.load`?

Comment: Please share your code and details of python runtime and path.  How did you download the model?

Comment: I added further details

Comment: If this isn't multiple Python installs, it could be that you installed the model without restarting your kernel. After installing a package, in order for the "entry point" to be registered you need to restart your kernel.

Answer (score 1):

First download it in the console:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then in the code you can use it:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Check out the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/models#quickstart).

##### Edit:

Since you downloaded the model already and it works when you provide the full path this might be a bug/issue with SpaCy not knowing where the already downloaded model is. I used to have similar problems e.g. when switching between conda environments (downloading the model in the default/system wide environment but running the code in a different environment).

Comment: Check out my Edit. Might also happen if you have multiple python versions and one is bound to `python3` and one to `python`, so you might run it in an IDE which then just runs the python script as `python` when you installed it in your `python3`.